# vtkAxis - remove decimal points from axis notation

Tags: c++, vtk

I need to display the value of the axis without decimal points in a vtkChart.

eg- If I have values 2.31, 4.76, 7.39 etc.. I want to display them on the axis as 2, 5, 7. As integers and not as doubles or floats.

I tried using PRINTF_NOTATION on vtkAxis::SetNotation(int notation), but it would display a single decimal point. 
Is there a way to achieve this in my chart using vtkAxis?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the format string, as in vtkAxis::SetLabelFormat("%1.0f")?

Comment: I'm using vtk 6.2, it doesn't have the SetLabelFormat function. Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

mululu's comment is correct. It should work with `SetLabelFormat("%1.0f")`,
but only with certain tick settings and notation according to the `vtkAxis::SetLabelFormat` documentation

> Get/Set the printf-style format string used when TickLabelAlgorithm is
>   TICK_SIMPLE and Notation is PRINTF_NOTATION.

I tried the following and it worked for me. vtk 8.0 on windows:

```
axis->SetNotation( vtkAxis::PRINTF_NOTATION );
axis->SetTickLabelAlgorithm( vtkAxis::TICK_SIMPLE );
axis->SetLabelFormat("%1.0f");
```

Comment: I'm using vtk 6.2, it doesn't have the SetLabelFormat or vtkAxis::PRINTF_NOTATION . Is there a workaround for it?

Comment: Hey Madz, did you try  vtkAxis::SetPrecision. Try setting it to 0.

Comment: Didn't work.. I'm trying to extend vtkChartXY and vtkAxis and add the vs.8 code.. I'll let you know if it works.